# How to decrease the memory consumption of Sidekiq processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've a server that launches 10 web applications that are almost identical (only assets and content are different). These applications uses Sidekiq to send emails after successful submitting. The problem is in memory usage. Each process consumes 80-100MB of RAM.

I've already set up `concurrency: 1` for every project. Since the amount of jobs is small I want to somewhat combine these processes into one. How to do this? Is it reliable solution? Maybe, I should search for some memory leaks?

I'm not so experienced in this field so any advices are welcome.

Comment: How about centralizing all the email sending into a single sidekiq process to send out emails of all applications?

Comment: I have not even thought about this! Thanks! Moreover, I have another application where Sidekiq is run. But how would I connect to that sidekiq process from another application?

Comment: Sidekiq uses redis to for storing the job queues. As long as the sidekiq worker knows the Job class to execute whenever a job is pushed into the redis queue, he doesn't care which process or application enqueued it.

Answer (score 0):

You could centralize all the email sending into a single `sidekiq` process to send out the emails of all applications.

Here's a good answer about the details of sharing `sidekiq` between various apps:

[How to share worker among two different applications on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907596/how-to-share-worker-among-two-different-applications-on-heroku)